# How to convert columns from a dataframe to string?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I consumed the api
converted to json, normalized with pandas, and converted to dataframe with pyspark.

But I can't change the columns, neither form nor anything, I can't select them.

I wonder where I'm going wrong!

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd  
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import os
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
from pyspark.sql import types


base_url = "https://api.talkwalker.com/api/v1/search/results"
token = "demo"
search = "cats"


url = base_url + "?access_token=" + token + "&q=" + search + "&pretty=true&hpp=1"


response = requests.get(url)
#print(response.text)

js = response.json()

df1 = pd.json_normalize(js['result_content'],['data'])

pdf = pd.DataFrame(df1)

df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)

display(df.select('data.url'))
```

problems are in the select.

Comment: Your example code is not working. There is a syntax error in line 4. Did you run this code? Can you please show your error code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark by default interprets column names with dots as struct elements, so if you want to get columns with names containing dots, you need to wrap the name with backticks. Try to do `` df.select('`data.url`') `` and see if that works.